# Sent my resume to a recruiter but not heard back. Should I follow up?

Tags: resume, software-industry, recruitment, follow-up

I am in contact with a recruiter for a Company. This is the second time I've been in contact with this person. The first time was several months ago, and after an internal recommendation and several rounds of phone interviews, I was told to try again after graduation.

So I did. Several weeks ago, I sent this person my updated resume and they seemed enthusiastic about my trying again. The recruiter said my resume had been forwarded onto engineering for review.

The recruiter has been good about following up with me in the past, but I still haven't heard back. I *do not want to push or seem needy* (since I'm employed), so I've held off following up via email.

**Should I send a follow up email?** Nothing too pushy. Just to reaffirm my enthusiasm and see if any progress has been made. I know the *recruiter isn't responsible for reviewing my resume*, engineering is. At worst, all I will hear is "I haven't heard back".

Comment: You could send an email if you like, but I'd just leave it.  It's likely that the engineering team isn't hiring right now so prompting won't do much except annoy them.

Comment: @JaneS I should mention, they are hiring. There are jobs posted and the recruiter mentioned the availability in the email.

Comment: @mcknz Slightly different as they are haven't had a formal interview yet (and have history purely by networking). I'm on the fence about it. Maybe a revised title instead?

Comment: @Codingo The specifics may be different but the general question (and therefore the answers) are largely the same. Agree with the duplicate. Perhaps a canonical "How and when do I follow up?" question might be a good idea though.

Answer (score 5):

The recruiter is your buffer between the business and yourself. You seem concerned about being too pushy - but a  recruiter helps to avoid this. They're going to let you know where you stand if you ask and you should expect that your follow up won't go to the company unless the recruiter thinks that it's necessary.

I would send a follow up to remind them about your application. Use the original e-mail and reply-all on it, this will retain the context for them and save them from having to go looking for it themselves. Something casual along the lines of:

> Hi x,
>
> Just touching base to see where we're at with this one?
>
> Regards,
>
> y

If the e-mail is ignored I would probably leave it at that and keep an eye out for future opportunities. Chances are they may already have an applicant in mind for this position, or that the recruiter has been busy and simply forgotten to get back to you. A casual followup shouldn't hurt in this case.