# Headhunted then headhunter went silent

Tags: recruitment, linkedin

I am currently in employment, and was headhunted by a Multi national tech company, one that I have always wanted to work for; a department head found my Linkedin profile, connected with me, and told me that if I was interested to connect and send my CV.

I did exactly that.

2 weeks later, I have heard nothing back despite sending a quick follow up message to find out if the person was still interested in putting me forward for the role.

I am currently scratching my head, and wondering why the person would go through all of that effort without even inviting me for an interview or more to the point let me know about the status of my application. My CV is exactly the same as my Linkedin profile.

Can anyone shed light on this please?

Comment: Did you receive _official_ contact details, e-mail address, name/title of the individual, phone number, etc. with company branding, regarding this person/position? Did you get a job description? Was there an advertisement placed for the position? Did you call the company's HR department and ask if they are currently recruiting for X position and that you spoke with ABC about it? The situation seems sketchy. I would have requested he/she e-mail me the job description and his/her contact details for me to review and respond to (this why [you] can weed out "crap" calls or fake scams).

Comment: They just briefly told me that they were looking for a project manager, and told me that if I am interested to send my CV. Linkedin profile shows that they worked at company mentioned, and had the usual career/education history. Can't find anything official yet.

Comment: Not enough information:  if you could respond to @B1313's questions, we could give an answer.  Right now it sounds like a  phishing scam.  More details please:  Edited to add:  Call the company and ask for that person by name.  If you get him/her, question them.  If you get "that person no longer works here" or  "I'm sorry, we don't have a <person's name> working at the company", you know it's a scam"

Comment: If this company is Google or any other alike conglomerate, it is probably not phishing but some extra eager, fresh hire recruiter is reaching out, grasping little strands to prove himself or herself. Probably after receiving the CV, (s)he put it in the sytem but did not get any interest from the hiring manager. Then promptly moved ont to the next candidate. No need to hurry the bad news (which might not be bad news in the long run) to the applicant. A Google recruiter did the same to me. Nothing to waste any brain activity on.

Comment: @MelBurslan If it's claiming to be a department head, it's not a fresh hire, or a recruiting agency.  Sounds fishy, or phishy if you prefer.

Comment: Yes, that is correct, it is a department head.

Comment: I don't think anyone could shed light on his/her motivations except the person themselves. There's a range of possibilities but I doubt it's constructive to pursue them.

Comment: You weren't headhunted, you had someone's in house recruiter reach out as you may have been a potential hire,  but when they saw your cv you weren't.   A headhunter approaches someone with an offer as they've already decided on hiring,  different thing. A headhunter will make an offer to the CEO of a competitor to defect and bring whatever makes the competitor better to you.

Comment: Sounds odd.  If it is not legit then it is a poor front.  It is too easy to check if someone is actually a manager at a company.   And they risk getting called out for a fake LinkIN.   May just be a flaky manager.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sent my resume to a recruiter but not heard back. Should I follow up?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/57496/sent-my-resume-to-a-recruiter-but-not-heard-back-should-i-follow-up)

Comment: @TheWanderingDevManager they were a department head, not an internal recruiter (where I also get Linkedin messages from), that's why I thought that I was headhunted.

Comment: Think this has turned out to be a scam, I went into their profile and did a Google image search, and found exactly the same Linkedin Profile but with a different name!!!!!

Comment: And no doubt they're now using your resume to try and get a job and work permit.

Comment: I have notified linkedin, reported profile as misrepresentative

Comment: @bobo2000 - not sure what you can do about this one, but learn and do what you did BEFORE you respond next time.

Answer (score 1):

Recruiters, or headhunters, employed by large companies have the specific job to find likely candidates and send them to hiring managers who want to hire more people. This is the recruiters only job. They are generally fast and efficient, but their job ends when they have sent your resume to the hiring managers.

Hiring managers have lots of responsibilities, and looking at resumes is only a small part of it. Your resume may be sitting on her desk waiting for her to get a free five minutes to look at it. If its a busy season that might be days or weeks away. If they like your resume you will be entered into the process of deciding who to invite for interview, and that may involve several other busy people.

In other words, the speed of the next stages doesn't depend at all on the speed the first stage took; likewise just because it takes a long time doesn't mean they don't like you as much as they thought. It just means these things take time.

However a couple of weeks is long enough to wait. Assuming that this was a legitimate in-company recruiter, get in touch and ask how long you should expect to wait before you hear from them again. Then leave it until that time has passed before contacting them again.

Comment: Downvoter want to explain?

Comment: Further point is the recruiter may have passed the resume along to the right person who may have decided not to interview you based on the other resumes received. The recruiter rarely makes the final cut as to who to interview. People eliminated from consideration are only rarely informed.

Comment: Or the guy who asked for your resume got laid off the next day. Or the opening got frozen for budget reasons, etc. These things happen. Be assured that if they are interested, they will eventually contact you. In the mean time, move on to other possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

There can be several reasons why this has happened to you.

IF this is a legitimate person working at the company:

- They could be resume farming (wanting a pool of candidates for a future date to avoid recruiter fees)
- They could be waiting for funding for a new position.
- They could be putting together a project.
- They could be on/getting ready for a vacation, and you are simply not a high priority.

If it is a scam....

- Phishing for personal information
- Trying to get a live email for spamming

Either way, I'd try following up by calling the company, getting into the company directory, and leaving a voicemail for the person.  Do this after hours so you can leave the message.  State that you are just following up, per his email to you, and leave your number.

If it's someone posing as him, he'll be wondering who you are and what you're talking about.  If it's not, he'll appreciate the initiative.

win-win